# How to load the global "vim" object so lua-language-server stops complaining

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp

Here is how I start the server:

```
-- LSP
vim.lsp.start({
  name = 'lua-language-server',
  cmd = { 'lua-language-server' },
  root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find({'.git', '.vim', 'nvim'}, { upward = true })[1])
})
```

This is fine. So now I load a `lua` file in vim, and one that takes advantage of the `vim` global object that `nvim` loads somewhere into the lua engine.

My linter doesn't have this library loaded, so it complains about the unset global. My lua code is able to run fine despite these linter warnings, of course.

How can I fix this? How can I straighten out the difference between my TRUE project root (effectively somewhere in `nvim`?) and my expressed one.

---

Idk if this helps:

```
:!lua-language-server --version
3.6.22
```

Comment: Another thing I will do is load `hs` objects when I open a file up in `~/.hammerspoon`. I love that I can easily code up this power in my `ftplugin` file, but DANG I'm struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recognize global objects:

```lua
vim.lsp.start({
  name = 'lua-language-server',
  cmd = { 'lua-language-server' },
  root_dir = vim.fs.dirname(vim.fs.find({'.git', '.vim', 'nvim'}, { upward = true })[1]),
  settings = { Lua = { diagnostics = { globals = {'vim'} } } },
})
```

Alternatively, use a [.luarc.json](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Configuration-File) file for workspace configs.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sumneko/vscode-lua/master/setting/schema.json",
    "diagnostics.globals": ["vim"]
}
```

See https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Settings for more settings. You might be interested in [#workspace library](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Settings#workspacelibrary)

For vim development, the above suppress warnings. The lsp does not know what's in the vim global. I use [neodev](https://github.com/folke/neodev.nvim) plugin for neovim lua development.

You can also look at configurations from lspconfig [here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/lua_ls.lua) and [here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#lua_ls). I think most people just install the extension, but you should be able to adapt it if you don't want to install it.

Comment: “Most people” citation needed

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I guess it's "most people I know / found online". This is the first time I've seen someone setting up LSP without lspconfig, although I do think being able to manually configuring LSP has its benefits.

Comment: Still more opinion than fact; I recommend rewording but I won’t plead the case further :)